# getBoundingClientRect() is giving dimensions of parent instead of target element

Tags: javascript, css-grid

I'm rather new to webdesign, so apologies in advance. I have a simple grid layout for a website. Inside of one of the cells is an image with object-fit: contain to make it responsive.

I am trying to get the actual dimensions of the image as it is displayed. The problem is that getBoundingClientRect() gives me the dimensions of the parent div, not the image itself. The whole reason I want the image size is to account for the letter-boxing.

Below you can easily see that width > height according to the function, even though I've used a portrait format example image. So it's taking the values from the parent.

EDIT for clarification: I see now that those are the right values of the img tag but not of the actual image. Any way to get those values?

```js
function getImageSize() {
  const image = document.querySelector('#sample_image');
  var imgBounds = image.getBoundingClientRect();
  console.log(imgBounds);
}
window.onload = getImageSize;
window.onresize = getImageSize;
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: grid;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: red;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(5, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 10px;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}

.instructions {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: blue;
  grid-column: 1 / -1;
  grid-row: 1;
}

.elements {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: yellow;
  grid-column: 1;
  grid-row: 2 / -1;
}

.examples {
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: violet;
  grid-column: 2 / -1;
  grid-row: 2 / -1;
  background-color: #d3d3d3;
  position: relative;
}

.examples img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  object-fit: contain;
}
```

```html
<html>

  <body>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div class="instructions">text1</div>
      <div class="elements">text2</div>
      <div class="examples">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/9/9b/Gustav_chocolate.jpg" id="sample_image" />
      </div>
    </div>

  </body>

</html>
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ash5cjwf/) which shows the problem as well.

Comment: It does give you the dimensions of the `img` tag. If you check inspect element and go under Computed, you'll see that the dimensions matches the image. Remove `width: 100%;` if you don't want your `img` element to stretch.

Comment: @Steffen You're right, I see that those are actually the dimensions of the image tag - but not of the image itself, which is what I'm interested in. Any chance to get those values? (I'm using anchored <a>'s with absolute position in % to approximate a responsive image map but because the values are not those of the actual image, rescaling breaks the positions.) I can't remove the width:100% as then the image wouldn't scale with the parent horizontally.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the image size (height & width) using JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/623172/how-to-get-the-image-size-height-width-using-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

To get the actual dimensions of the image itself, you can use the naturalWidth and naturalHeight properties of the image element in JavaScript. Here's how you can modify your function to retrieve the dimensions of the image:

```
function getImageSize() {
  const image = document.querySelector('#sample_image');
  const imgWidth = image.naturalWidth;
  const imgHeight = image.naturalHeight;
  console.log('Image Width:', imgWidth, 'Image Height:', imgHeight);
}

window.onload = getImageSize;
window.onresize = getImageSize;
```

This will give you the actual width and height of the image content itself, regardless of how it is being displayed in the parent container.